# Python Pandas Remove Duplicate Rows Based on Grouping

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have a Pandas DataFrame which contains sentences and their corresponding tokens such as the following:

```
    sent_id id  token
1   1       1   my
2   1       2   name
3   1       3   is
4   1       4   John
5   1       5   .
6   2       1   John
7   2       2   is
8   2       3   a
9   2       4   good
10  2       5   man
11  2       6   .
...
```

I want to remove duplicated sentences from this dataframe, that is, based on the sentence id, remove all rows if tokens matched previously. For example, if there is another sentence with the tokens `"my name is John ."` (with the same order), I want to remove all the rows of that sentence. How can I achieve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `groupby` and form the sentence using values in token. Check if any of these sentences are duplicated with `duplicated`. Use the index of this result to filter your original dataframe:

```
dup_ix = df.groupby('sent_id')['token'].apply(' '.join).duplicated()
good_id = dup_ix[~dup_ix].index
df[df['sent_id'].isin(good_id)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['sent'] = np.array([None]*len(df))
for i in df.sent_id.unique():
    df.loc[df.sent_id==i, 'sent'] = df[df.sent_id==i].sent.apply(lambda x :' '.join(df[df.sent_id==i].token))
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['id', 'token', 'sent'], keep='first')
df = df.drop(['sent'], axis=1)
```